# Independently thinking student

Tags: word-request

> What is the one word for an independent thinker, who comes up with ideas and then does not hesitate in voicing them before the audience?

I'm looking to apply the word in context of a high school student, where the audience would refer to his/her classmates and teachers.

Comment: "**individual**" comes to mind.

Comment: @GaurangTandon How about "freethinker"?

Comment: @Gustavson It doesn't relate to the part about "not hesitating to voice them before an audience". In fact, the word "freethinker" is along the lines of *a person who rejects accepted opinions*, certainly not what I am want.

Comment: @SovereignSun That feels more like "isolated" or separated from the group...

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to your question and they do not necessarily overlap:

1. is an independent thinker, who comes up with ideas:

*authentic* (thanks to @Ced)
*original*

2. does not hesitate to voice them before an audience

*outspoken

assertive

vociferous

forthright*
or even simply *self-confident*

Answer (score 0):

Depending on just how novel their ideas are, you might use ***radical***.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it an **authentic** thinker/leader/student/whatever..